# Getting Error while fetching youtube categories list in laravel

Tags: php, youtube, laravel-5.3

I got this error:

> Undefined property: Dawson\Youtube\Youtube::$videoCategories

This is my controller categories method

```
public function categories()
{
  $youtube = \App::make('youtube');

  $categories = $youtube->videoCategories->listVideoCategories('snippet', ['regionCode' => 'MA']);
  print_r($categories);
  dump($categories);
}
```

Comment: you must tell what is the error you are receiving!?

Comment: @Atiqur am getting Undefined property: Dawson\Youtube\Youtube::$videoCategories this error am getting  when i try to run